# MySQLi bind_param returning only one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

Despite coming from a programming background, I'm still relatively new to PHP and trying to grasp it properly. I have decided to use MySQLi instead of PDO (which turned out to be a grave mistake on my part) for my database needs, but I've run into an issue where bind_result only seems to return one result, despite the results, to my knowledge, being looped through. I've been googling for hours, but I just can't figure out what's going on. I'm sure the solution is very simple, I'm overlooking something, and/or am doing something terribly wrong. If so, I hope you can find it in your heart to forgive me and help me solve my pesky issue, Stack Overflow.

[Here is the ever-so-malicious code.](http://privatepaste.com/81a53b01ea/poadslcaw)

```
public function query($query, $types, $params)
{
    if ($stmt = $this->prepareQuery($query, $types, $params))
    {
        $stmt->execute();

        // we prepare the array in which the results will be stored for dynamic results
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $results = array();
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
        {
            $name = $field->name;
            $$name = null;
            // pass reference because bind_result() requires it
            $results[$name] = &$$name;
        }

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            // call_user_func_array is used for dynamic results
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_result"), $results);

            var_dump($results) . "<br />";
        }

        $data = array();
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            array_push($data, $results);
        }
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $this->db->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `call_user_func_array()` inside `while ($stmt->fetch())` looks suspect.You should not be binding in a loop; call it instead on its own. Your subsequent `fetch()` look which builds `$data` should work then.

Comment: why you're using 2 while?

Comment: +1 by the way, for the question from a *programmer*, which is extremely rare thing in this part of SO...

Comment: a hint: make $types param optional, and use `s` for all variables by default

Comment: I am eager to know had you this fix solved or not.

Comment: The double while loop was due to my sleep deprivation affecting my common sense. However, I am now at a situation where it does appear to return the right amount of rows, but adds the same row to my `$data` array multiple times. It's almost as if it isn't actually updating the results after calling `$stmt->fetch()`. This is the reason I put it in the while loop to begin with. [Here's my updated code.](http://privatepaste.com/65f543573c/lkmsdfoie) -- Thanks for the hint. I'll implement it once this works. Also, I mentioned that as a joke to emphasise my stupidity at that hour of the day.